# RestKit willMapData:

Tags: objective-c, restkit

The following code receives a JSON response from my server, which consists of an array of elements, each having a 'created_at' and an 'updated_at' key. For all of these elements, I want to remove a single character (a colon) in the strings that are set for these two keys.

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)loader willMapData:(inout id *)mappableData {
    // Convert the ISO 8601 date's colon in the time-zone offset to be easily parsable
    // by Objective-C's NSDateFormatter (which works according to RFC 822).
    // Simply remove the colon (:) that divides the hours from the minutes:
    // 2011-07-13T04:58:56-07:00 --> 2011-07-13T04:58:56-0700 (delete the 22nd char)
    NSArray *dateKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"created_at", @"updated_at", nil];
    for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)*mappableData])
    for(NSString *dateKey in dateKeys) {
        NSString *ISO8601Value = (NSString*)[dict valueForKey:dateKey];
        NSMutableString *RFC822Value = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:ISO8601Value];
        [RFC822Value deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(22, 1)];
        [dict setValue:RFC822Value forKey:dateKey];
        [RFC822Value release];
    }
}
```

However, the line `[dict setValue:RFC822Value forKey:dateKey];` raises an `NSUnknownKeyException` with the message `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key created_at`.

What am I doing wrong here? My main issue is maybe that I don't really feel comfortable with this inout declaration...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your inout declaration looks OK to me. I suggest you to print mappableData with NSLog to see what does it actually look like.

**Edit:** Based on the discussion in the comments, `mappableData` in this case is actually a collection of `JKDictionary` objects. `JKDictionary` is defined in `JSONKit.h` (a JSON parsing library that RestKit is using) as a subclass of `NSDictionary`. Therefore, it's not a mutable dictionary and does **not** implement `[NSMutableDictionary setValue:forKey:]`. That's why you're getting NSUnknownKeyException during runtime.

One way to achieve what you want could be something like that (not tested!):

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)loader willMapData:(inout id *)mappableData {
    // Convert the ISO 8601 date's colon in the time-zone offset to be easily parsable
    // by Objective-C's NSDateFormatter (which works according to RFC 822).
    // Simply remove the colon (:) that divides the hours from the minutes:
    // 2011-07-13T04:58:56-07:00 --> 2011-07-13T04:58:56-0700 (delete the 22nd char)
    NSArray *dateKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"created_at", @"updated_at", nil];
    NSMutableArray *reformattedData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[*mappableData count]];

    for(id dict in [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)*mappableData]) {
        NSMutableDictionary* newDict = [dict mutableCopy];
        for(NSString *dateKey in dateKeys) {
            NSMutableString *RFC822Value = [[newDict valueForKey:dateKey] mutableCopy];
            [RFC822Value deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(22, 1)];
            [newDict setValue:RFC822Value forKey:dateKey];
        }
        [reformattedData addObject:newDict];
    }
    *mappableData = reformattedData;
}
```

Comment: Well, the output looks as I would expect it to: (excerpt) `(
        {
        "_id" = 4e1c19b52273d60001000007;
        "created_at" = "2011-07-12T02:55:29-07:00";
        "updated_at" = "2011-07-12T02:55:29-07:00";
        "user_id" = 4d1180941f6df60518000002;
    }
)`

Comment: That strange. What happens when you log dict around the offending statement? What does it print? Are you sure it's a mutable dictionary?

Comment: Looks identical to the output above, only without the normal brackets. Which makes sense to me, cause it's not an array anymore but only one dict entry then. Also, one of the RestKit specs does (in my eyes) exactly what I want to do, even without any casting: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Specs/ObjectMapping/RKObjectLoaderSpec.m#L75

Comment: My other idea is to replace 'for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in' with 'for(id dict in' and log [dict Class] before the offending statement.

Comment: JKDictionary is what it tells me.

Comment: That's one way to do it. NOTE: In RestKit versions 0.10+ they now include an ISO8601Parser so you shouldn't need to do this yourself anymore!